# CSS, center two <p> elements on the body (at same line)

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make two

elements to be centered in the middle of the page. The elements must be at same line.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="paragraph-wrapper">
    <p class="white-text">Foo? </p><p class="orange-text">Bar.</p>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.paragraph-wrapper p {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

p.white-text {
    color: white
}

p.orange-text {
    color: orange;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the `text-align: center;` property to `.paragraph-wrapper`, not to the p-tags:

```css
.paragraph-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #000;
}
.paragraph-wrapper p {
    display: inline-block;
}

p.white-text {
    color: white
}

p.orange-text {
    color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="paragraph-wrapper">
    <p class="white-text">Foo? </p><p class="orange-text">Bar.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox if you want:

```
.paragraph-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `text-align: center` on the parent in your example

```css
.paragraph-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}

.paragraph-wrapper p {
  display: inline-block;
}

p.white-text {
  color: green;
}

p.orange-text {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="paragraph-wrapper">
    <p class="white-text">Foo? </p><p class="orange-text">Bar.</p>
</div>
```